# Upload Image with FileUpload and Stock in database

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, webforms

I want to Upload a Image with FileUpload and store it in database and the code for it is this :

```
string filePath =  FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
string contenttype = String.Empty;

//Set the contenttype based on File Extension
if (contenttype != String.Empty)
{
    Stream fs = FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream;
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
    Byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((Int32)fs.Length);

    //insert the file into database
    f.photo = Convert.ToString(FileUpload1.FileBytes);
    Label1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
    Label1.Text = "File Uploaded Successfully";
}
```

but I get this error:

```
error :Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
in 
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

What is causing this?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code for uploading:

```
string strRealPath = Request.PhysicalApplicationPath;
if(FileUpload1.HasFile)
{
    string fileName = FileUpload1.FileName; 
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(strRealPath + fileName);
    //Now insert the file into the database.
}
```

Comment: MohamedGooner how i can insert the file into database i am using framwork entity f.photo = FileUpload1.HasFile.ToString();

Comment: You can use SQL statement for inserting into your database.
Use a simple insert sql statement, you can see some explainations on the internet for writing sql statements.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is occuring here:

```
string filePath =  FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;
```

If this is null (which it is) - then your call to this:

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
```

Will give you that error, as you're passing a string object which hasn't been initialised correctly.

Try stepping through with the debugger to see why this is occuring.

Answer (score 0):

change the code a bit, as follows

```
//on upload button click
  if(FileUploadControl.HasFile)
    {
        try
        {
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUploadControl.FileName);
            FileUploadControl.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload status: File uploaded!";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            StatusLabel.Text = "Upload error:" + ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1757/File-Upload-with-ASP-NET